# whatsapp business api docker images hash values from trusted repository

Tags: whatsapp

One of my project , my security team asking me to share the whatsapp business api docker images hash values to promote docker images to our own docker repository.

These values i couldn't find in facebook whatsapp documentation .

After pulling the images i can get the hash values but security team wants to compare the downloaded one is the proper one or not .

```
  docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp
  docker.whatsapp.biz/web
```

How can i access the whatsapp business api docker repository in internet ? Any lead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the URL where i can get the digest value of the whatsapp buinsess api

```
https://bintray.com/whatsapp
https://bintray.com/whatsapp/dkr-releases/web
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
docker images --digests
```